# CentOS 7.2 Minimal Time synchronization timedated and/or ntpd/chrony

Tags: centos, systemd, ntpd

Environment: KVM CentOS 7.2 Minimal installation.

I am trying to sync the time with an NTP server in my network.

My Proxmox-Host (Debian based) is able to do this by enabling `systemd-timesyncd`combined with a configuration file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

The CentOS 7.2 installation just got `systemd-timedated` and with the command `timedatectl` NTP is just available if I install the package `chronyd` or `ntp`.

Question: 
Is the NTP-Client-Part of systemd (in Proxmox timesyncd) not included in CentOS / RedHat 7 and I definitely need `chronyd` or `ntpd`?

Comment: if I understand your question, yes, you must install the chrony or ntp rpm for time sync to work.

Comment: So the ntp-component of timedated is bot available at CentOS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it appears that RedHat chose to compile `systemd` without `systemd-timesyncd` feature.

Comment: Is there an explanation for this, some what, absurd decision ?

Comment: seems like chronyd is used by default